# How to use Parse xml from XML library using Robot framework

Tags: xml, robotframework

I am trying to use the keyword "Set Element Attribute" from the library "XML" in Robot Framework. From the user guide [Set Element Attribute](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html#Set%20Element%20Attribute) the structure of this command should be something like:

```
Set Element Attribute   source   name   value    xpath
```

I am wondering how to specify the "source". I look into documentation and it seems like I have to use the Parse XML keyword but I have no idea how to do that so that it refers to the webpage exactly as I have it when I want to modify the element attribute.

With the regular RF keywords I normally specify the ID of the element and it finds it, without specifying the source.

Answer (score 0):

The example for the [`Set Element Attribute`](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html#Set%20Element%20Attribute) is the following:

> ```
> Set Element Attribute     ${XML}  attr    value   
> Element Attribute Should Be   ${XML}  attr    value
> ```

Above this there is a link [Example](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/XML.html#Example) which says:

> In this example, as well as in many other examples in this
> documentation, `${XML}` refers to the following example XML document.
> In practice `${XML}` could either be a path to an XML file or it could
> contain the XML itself.

E.g.:

```
Set Element Attribute   ./folder/my.xml     attr    value
```

or:

```
${XML}=    Set Variable    <example><first id="1">text</first><example>
Set Element Attribute   ${XML}  first    value
```

Comment: @AnnaRamolini Let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Hi Bence, thannk you for your answer. I do not understand what I would put in substiution of "./folder/my.xml". how do I make that my webpage that I am trying to test? Thank you.

Comment: @AnnaRamolini Please edit your question and share details about how your webpage generates/acquires etc. the XML you have to pass to this keyword. Do you receive the XML as a payload of request or you have to download it from the page?

Comment: to be honest I have no idea. I have never worked with XML in RF. Normally I use "Open Browser" and the page opens and all the operations are done on the webpage and I don't have to acquire the XML. I would like to know how to do that. Thanks

Comment: @AnnaRamolini I am afraid I cannot help you with that as it sounds unique to your application. You could ask the developers of the application under test or the person who has specified the test case.